# Remote desktop connection fails with network level authentication

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

When attempting to connect to a Windows 7 computer on the same network with RDP I'm getting a message: "The remote computer requires Network Level Authentication"
It used to work but suddenly stopped working. I'm trying to connect from another Windows 7 machine that supports NLA.
When I turn this requirement off in the host machine I can connect to it. 
What is the reason it stopped working? How can I fix it?

Comment: If you start Remote Desktop Connection, click the icon in the upper-left corner of the Remote Desktop Connection dialog box, and then click About. In the About Remote Desktop Connection dialog box, do you see the phrase "Network Level Authentication supported"?  Which RDP version does it say it supports?

Comment: Have you tried using System Restore on either/both machines to go back to a point in time when it WAS working, to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Yes, NLA is supported (and works when I connect to other machine).

Comment: I didn't try system restore as it happened some time ago

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the problematic host from another NLA-enabled RDP client?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. The problem is in the host.